Having problem in code deploy during CICD pipeline
I was making CICD pipeline for angular app but facing error in code deploy stage and code is present in githhub. I tried all method but still this error is not resolving .
Error code
ScriptFailed
Script name
scripts/stop_nginx.sh
Message
Script at specified location: scripts/stop_nginx.sh run as user root failed with exit code 127
Logs
LifecycleEvent - BeforeInstall
Script - scripts/stop_nginx.sh
[stderr]bash: line 1: /opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/7c3950a2-5da6-45dc-a9cf-cb7e70ed622c/d-H64Z8P727/deployment-archive/scripts/stop_nginx.sh: cannot execute: required file not found


You have to create a appspec.yml file in your porject root directory
sample appspec.yml file is here
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:

source: /
destination: /var/www/html
file_exists_behavior: OVERWRITE
hooks:
BeforeInstall:  #trigger at step 2

location: ./script_path_to_run
timeout: 300
runas: root
AfterInstall: #trigger at step 3
location: ./.script_path_to_run
timeout: 300
runas: root
location: ./script_path_to_run
timeout: 2000
runas: root



